# Create .CSV file based on similar key in two data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pytorch

I would like to generate `.csv` file based on identical columns in ground truth prediction values. I have tried lots of ways but I am able to create single `.csv` file but unable to create an individual `.csv` file.

**main_predicted.csv**: It contains more than 4500 records with image name and prediction result

```
imgs    pred
imagenet_aeroplane_n02690373_10203_1.jpg    aeroplane
imagenet_aeroplane_n02690373_1038_0.jpg aeroplane
imagenet_aeroplane_n02690373_1119_2.jpg aeroplane
imagenet_aeroplane_n02690373_1295_0.jpg aeroplane
```

The other ground truth folder (specific class) `labels.csv` contains 568 records. I would like to generate a .csv file to match images name in both .csv and create new `.csv` file along with `imags` and `pred`

[image]

**Code** I am using below code to create one `.csv` file. Now, I want to match 2nd table imgs column with first table imgs columns and create a new table with imgs and pred names.

```
image_dir = np.array(sum(image_dir, []))
    preds = np.concatenate(preds)

    csv = {'imgs': np.array(image_dir), 'pred': np.array(preds),
           }
    csv = pd.DataFrame(csv)
    print(csv)

    csv.to_csv('evaluation/cls_ref/res/iid.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

read the file and filter with imgs from actual labels

```
img_preds = pd.read_csv('main_predicted.csv')

images = img_preds['imgs']

actual_labels = pd.read_csv('labels.csv')

output = img_preds[img_preds['imgs'].isin(actual_labels['imgs'].to_list())]
```